# React Axios useEffect hook, different types of errors when rendering to the user interface

Tags: reactjs, api, user-interface, axios, use-effect

I am pretty new to full stack, and im using MERN, so forgive me if this is an easy/silly fix (though I looked at several and different types of sources, with no luck thus fur).

I can not seem to render my array of items to reacts ui. I get the GET request and have logged it to the console so i Know its there but when i go and try and map it or put it into a div with a simple function to iterate it or just simply to display some information from the JSON file, i keep getting errors. Here is the JSON file (which passed a validation check) and the Component I'm working in.

```
   [
        {
            "_id": "5e1ff19d926f7c245ce01d7c",
            "foodmenu": [
                {
                    "food": "burger",
                    "orders": 0
                },
                {
                    "food": "fish",
                    "orders": 0
                },
                {
                    "food": "salad",
                    "orders": 0
                },
                {
                    "food": "curry",
                    "orders": 0
                },
                {
                    "food": "sushi",
                    "orders": 0
                },
                {
                    "food": "egg rolls",
                    "orders": 0
                },
                {
                    "food": "Jacket potatoe",
                    "orders": 0
                },
                {
                    "food": "hash browns",
                    "orders": 0
                },
                {
                    "food": "mash potatoe",
                    "orders": 0
                },
                {
                    "food": "pizza",
                    "orders": 0
                },
                {
                    "food": "sandwhich",
                    "orders": 0
                },
                {
                    "food": "omlete",
                    "orders": 0
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
```

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Orders() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios("api/orders/foodmenu/foodtypes");
      setData(result.data);
      console.log(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);


  return (

     <div>
    {data[0].foodmenu.map(data => (
      <div key={data._id}>{data.foodmenu}</div>
    ))}
    
  </div>

  )
 
};

export default Orders;
```

I get Type errors like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'foodmenu' of undefined
```

&

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Well when you say "errors" please specify what specifically the message is and if relevant what line it occurs. You're also overwriting the `data` variable which is just confusing and bound to cause problems. Currently it refers to both the data in the state, *and* each item in your map function. Name them different things. Also, I think in your map function, you want to return a div with the mapped item's values, not the state data values, e.g. `.map(item => <div key={item.food}>FOOD: {item.food}, ORDERS: {item.orders}</div>)`

Comment: I've specified the errors already....and its in the return block to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const tablelist = data.map((data, key) => {
              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{data.orderID}</td>
                  <td>{data.orderDateTime}</td>
                  <td>{data.priceTotal}</td>
)
```

Do this in your useeffect() and call {tablelist} inside return

Answer (score 0):

If you add a simple length check first, it should work. The problem is that the component is rendered before the data has loaded. This means that `data[0]` will be undefined and therefore accessing properties on it will fail.

Using a length check, since `&&` is evaluated lazily, your component will return false until your data array has elements inside it and not try to execute the rest of the code in the component.

```
return (data.length &&
   <div>
      {data[0].foodmenu.map(data => (
         <div key={data._id}>{data.foodmenu}</div>
      ))} 
  </div>)
```

Comment: Hi. Didn't work. A 0 just flashes on screen and goes away. The console spits out a warning saying. Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. But we've already provided a unique key in our div!?

Comment: Update - though when I replace the div with the key to an <li> tag, I get rendered bullet points but no information next to them!?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. First you need to validate the length before accessing `data[0]` because the array is empty before fetching data from server. Don't use same variable name `data` in both state and map function parameter. Though it works, it is not clear to read. Also you cannot use `data._id` as the key of mapped div because it need a unique value. In your scope, `data` variable is the local parameter, not the state. That is the reason for using another parameter name `item` instead of data. Also you can use the second parameter `index` in map function for the key. Finally you have to use proper display text like `{item.food} - {item.orders}` instead trying to print the object or array.

```
return (
  <div>
    {data.length > 0 && data[0].foodmenu.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={index}>{item.food} - {item.orders}</div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```